# All tab's content script get message no matter which tabId I pass into Chrome message api

Tags: google-chrome, message-passing

My extension used to work fine. but recently it is buggy. when I pass messages between background page and content script, no matter which tabId I pass into the function, all tab's content script will get the message. 
I'll just make an example.
if one time message exchange:
*Background page:*

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, "test");
```

*content script:*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (req, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log(req);
});
```

if I have two or more tabs running this content script, all of them will show the "test" string no matter what the passed tabId in background page is.

This also happens on long-live connections.
My chrome version is 46.0.2471.2 m and on another machine is 45.xxxx.

Comment: I think I am seeing a similar issue after upgrading Chrome to 45. Have you found out what is the source of the problem?

Comment: I have reported issue in crbug.com. I believe it's a bug..